# indexof function for a custom list

Tags: c#, list, windows-phone-7

I need to update an entry in a custom list which i created, the list is shown below:
`List<Data> Test = new List<Data>();`
I found some solutions proposed online such as using **FindIndex**, however this function is not present.
Note: I'm using **C#** in **windows phone 7 development** if this helps.
Thanks

Comment: So if i need to locate this entry in the list based on the name variable inside it, how should the indexof function be used?

To be clear, i need to update an entry in this list so i'm locating this entry first by finding the index then update it by:  
`Test[index]=XXXXX`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to find the object by an index, but by some field inside your class, you could do something like this. I'm assuming your DATA object has a unique ID field inside it...

```
var someName = "name_i_want_to_find";
var myItems = Test.FindAll(x => x.Name == someName);

foreach (var item in myItems)
    item.FieldToChange = "someNewValue";
```

Comment: I understand your answer, but this way i am saving my desired element in a new variable `var myItems` then updating the copy.  
I want to update the existing list itself, this is why i need to get the index or am i wrong??

Comment: I know that in the foreach there is no copying, but i meant by this line of code:  
`var myItems = Test.FindAll(x => x.Name == someName);`  
In this, we are getting the result in a new variable, isn't that right? So in the foreach i am updating the **myItems** variable not **Test**

Answer (score 1):

List has an [IndexOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bd0tetb.aspx) method, this is present in the Windows Phone 7 version.

Answer (score 0):

Use `IndexOf()` method directly. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e4w08k17.aspx)